# How to draw donought chart in chart.js with label, values and color

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart java script library for drawing charts in my application. when i am drawing don-ought chart it is working but i want to show some additional information with this like color icon, value and label. I have attached an image. Please find the attachment. i want to show the information in don-ought chart similar to this image. How can i display it. Please help. I am in need of a quick solution. [Image][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVoR0.png